# Debian installer, graphical installer, live image, hang on Dell Inspiron 27

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I'm attempting to setup Debian on a [Dell Inspiron All-in-One](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/desktop-computers/inspiron-27-all-in-one/spd/inspiron-27-7710-aio) system, either as dual boot or replacing the existing windows 10 OS.

The installer hangs after entering either the "graphical install", "install" or "live" options from the initial menu. I used the latest 64-bit installer: [debian-11.7.0-amd64-netinst.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-11.7.0-amd64-netinst.iso), burned onto a USB drive using the dd command:

```
sudo dd if=/debian-11.7.0-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sda
```

Here's a picture of the initial menu, and the hang:

[image: initial menu]
[image: installer hangs]

I suspect that UEFI/RAID settings may be involved so I'm including screenshots of the relevant BIOS settings:

Boot Configuration (1/3). Legacy Mode not supported??
[image: Boot Configuration (1/3) (Legacy Mode not supported??)]
Boot Configuration (2/3)
[image: Boot Configuration (2/3)]
Boot Configuration (3/3)
[image: Boot Configuration (3/3)]
Storage/RAID Configuration
[image: Storage/RAID Configuration]

Comment: Have you already tested the integrity of the RAM? Assuming the RAM is not an issue, was the disk used previously in Legacy/(IDE) mode?

Comment: Alternately, it may be some record on the drive from the previous Win 10 install that was created with Secure boot enabled that is disallowing the install to continue.

Comment: I searched in the BIOS but couldn't find any Memory Test available other than the Power-on-Self-Test: https://pasteboard.co/8Jm3jddGpecA.jpg 

I did lower the priority of the "Windows Boot Manager" which was preventing me from booting off the USB, and I'm able to successfully boot into the USB and enter the debian installer initial menu, but installation hangs with no explanation or error message.

Comment: In the advanced options of the Debian install menu there should be an option to check memory, iirc.

Comment: Any option I chose from the advanced options results in the hang as well.

Comment: I did run BIOS memory and system tests which all passed: https://pasteboard.co/uQLAnzAyoxeB.jpg Also the original WIndows was working fine.

Comment: From here, I see two paths forward - adjusting the UEFI boot settings/Secure Boot; Or checking/recreating your install media.
Secure boot is disabled so I wouldn't think it should be an issue, so I lean towards trying a new install medium.

Comment: Looking closer at the ISO you chose to install from, I think it may be that you are using the net install, which is failing to complete, probably due to some issue connecting to the internet. 
If you don't have any limitations requiring you to use this ISO, I would suggest a more complete release:
https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-11.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso

Comment: I used the DVD and also I've used the netinstall before without any internet access using the same media on a different machine. There is something strange with the installer on this machine.

Comment: It seems to be so. I am very sorry I don't have a good answer to this issue. 
Looking at this again, I am wondering if you tried turning on "Enable Microsoft UEFI CA" in the BIOS? And if it produced any errors or a different result?